# Sort a sheet by a column while grouping rows with same value in another column

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a sheet detailing a list of projects assigned to project workers and their progress status (1 - waiting approval, 2 started, 3 in progress, 4 completed). An individual can have multiple projects assigned to them. I would like to sort the spreadsheet by status (in descending order) but also grouping all the project workers together like in the example below.

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Tom | Project A | Status 4 |
| Tom | Project B | Status 1 |
| Paul | Project C | Status 4 |
| John | Project D | Status 3 |
| John | Project E | Status 1 |
| Tim | Project F | Status 2 |
| Tim | Project G | Status 1 |
| Carl | Project H | Status 1 |

The original data sorted by Status shows like the example below:

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Tom | Project A | Status 4 |
| Paul | Project C | Status 4 |
| John | Project D | Status 3 |
| Tim | Project F | Status 2 |
| Tom | Project B | Status 1 |
| John | Project E | Status 1 |
| Tim | Project G | Status 1 |

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Showing what the expected result is would be helpful

Answer (score -1):

Simply sort by the workers column **first** and then sort by status. Excel will "retain" the previous assortment as the in-group rule, if that makes sense.

If you want to perform something more complex you can use [this](https://trumpexcel.com/multiple-level-sorting-excel/) as a guide

Comment: that won't work because my priority is to show on top all project in status 4, and only if a worker has multiple project showing them grouped together. If I sort by worker first, someone called Alex with only a project in status 1 will show on top. Not sure if that makes sense?

Comment: I meant to say sort by project first than status. Did you read the link I posted?